# When installing LAMP... should I install Apache, MySQL Server then PHP or Apache, PHP then MySQL Server?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I have an Ubuntu 10.04 server and want a perfect/optimal installation.

After installing Apache, should I install MySQL Server next or PHP next? Does it matter? Will there be any errors if I go either way? Are there any dependencies on the other being installed first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter.  As long as Apache is installed before the PHP package then you are good to go. (Because when you install the PHP package some distributions do some auto-configuring with Apache).

Comment: Feel free to file bug reports against any distribution that does different things when PHP and Apache are installed in different orders. That's just silly...